# How can I block some checkboxes from being selected by a condition?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I block some checkboxes from being selected by a condition? For example, if `input[value="Animals"]` is highlighted, so that `input[value="Insects"]` cannot be highlighted and vice versa?

This example is minified, there are many more checkboxes and exception parameters, I would like to know the logic behind setting conditions. I would be grateful if the answer is accompanied by a code

Comment: Do you want that the checkbox will be checked by default?

Comment: @YarinLevi yes, there is default checkbox `<input type="checkbox" value="all">`

Comment: _"I would like to know the logic behind setting conditions"_ - For this there would have to be an actual rule set to implement. Right now this "question" is way too broad.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `css`?

Comment: Why no radio buttons?

Comment: @Andreas because there could be several options

Comment: You can accomplish this with change handlers and a lot of conditional logic blocks that update the behavior of the form UI.  This can easily become unwieldy and difficult to maintain, in which case you can either grab a library that accomplishes it more declaratively or update your own implementation to allow a higher degree of abstraction.  Given how broad the original question is, this is about as focused an answer that can realistically/reasonably be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
if(input.is(':checked')) {
    otherinput.prop('disabled', true)
} else if (input.prop('checked', false)) {
    otherinput.prop('disabled', false)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d204uxt9/